# Eclipse New class , MapActivity not found !

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to create new class MapActivity from Eclipse.

I go File-> New -> Class on Superclass-> Browse, and when I type MapActivity  there is no results.

In Windows-> Android SDK and AVD Manager there is no new updates, I have installed SDK from version 1.5 to 2.2

Can some one help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select GoogleAPI by Google Inc package installed , create an AVD profile using the same and then use map activity..This should help you ...

Answer (score 4):

The steps Ravi mentioned are necessary, but to get things working in your existing eclipse project, without creating a new one, change the build target:

Project Properties->Android->Google APIs (x)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "Google APIs by Google Inc." package installed for the API version you're using.  MapActivity isn't included in the standard Android API.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you build target has Google APIs included. In eclipse this is done in project properties in the android menu.

2) If using emulator - the AVD must also target an api with Google APIs included.

3) Add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` as child (inside) the application-tag in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse id, then click on AVD Manager and then it will show you the list of installed as well as un-installed packages. Select Google api packages and click on install. Then you will not this problem.

[See the details](http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-mapactivity-is-not-found.html)